# Access violation Error in C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, access-violation

I have C# windows form project on VS2013.
my graphic support by MFC C++ project through dll.
when I use 32 bit dll and 32bit C# project it's work fine.
but when use 64bit dll and 64bit C# project only work with .net framework 4 client profile and not work on .net framework 4.5 and get access violation error when use dll.
code that throw access violation error on C++ dll.

```
BOOL ImportElevation( CString &csFileName )
{
CString csTmpPath = GetTempFolderName(csFileName.GetBuffer());

int iResult = vtCreateDir(csTmpPath);
if (iResult == 0 && errno != EEXIST)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,_T("Couldn't create temporary directory to hold contents of archive."),
        _T("Error"),MB_ICONERROR);
    return FALSE;   // no layers created
}

CString csUnzipPath = csTmpPath + _T("/");
iResult = ExpandZip(csFileName, csUnzipPath, ProgressCallback);
if (iResult == 1)
{
    // the archive contained a single file
    std::string strPathName = (const char *) csUnzipPath;
    for (dir_iter it(strPathName); it != dir_iter(); ++it)//at this line throw exception
    {
        if (it.is_directory())
            continue;
        csUnzipPath += it.filename().c_str();
        break;
    }
    CElevLayer* pLayer = new CElevLayer(csFileName);
    if(pLayer->ImportElevation(csUnzipPath,TRUE,ProgressCallback))
    {
        m_vecElevLayer.push_back(pLayer);

        m_iActiveLayerIdx = m_vecElevLayer.size()-1;

        pLayer->CreateMap(ProgressCallback);

        return TRUE;
    }
    else
        SAFE_DELETE(pLayer);

    return FALSE;
}

// clean up after ourselves
csTmpPath = GetTempFolderName(csUnzipPath);
vtDestroyDir(csTmpPath);

return TRUE;
}
```

I run this dll on 3 different projects and get this error.

Comment: Maybe not related to your problem, but after calling `GetBuffer()` you should call `ReleaseBuffer()` at some point.

Comment: The cast `(const char *) csUnzipPath;` looks strange. Are you sure that `csUnzipPath` is not a Unicode string?

Comment: my problem isn't these. this work of 32 bit fine and work with .net framework 4 profile fine. but when use .net framework 4.5 with 64 bit throw exception.

Comment: Well, at least I've seen some things breaking between 32-bit and 64-bit because of different encodings. Anyway, the cast looks dangerous.

Comment: @honk it's depended to version of .net framework?